# La función no detecta el nuevo valor del atributo de un elemento, e itera sobre el antiguo. Tamagotchi

Tags: javascript, vanilla

Estoy haciendo un Tamagotchi :(

tengo barras de progreso de los niveles de suciedad, hambre, sueño etc.
por defecto al inicio están todas al 100% y con el método, ¨mover_barra¨con un setInterval va reduciendo su value secuencialmente.

el objetivo es que cuándo pulse el botón duchar, se restablezca los valores de la barra de progreso ¨suciedad¨ al 100% y continue otra vez con el retroceso.

Pero no, la función sigue iterando con los valores antiguos, solo pone al 100% la barra de progreso durante un segundo y luego vuelve a su valor anterior.

ayuda :(

***PD: tengo que usar 100% javaScript vanilla.***

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="tamagochi2.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tamagochi.css" type="text/css" >
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="container-img">
            <img src='./img/gato.png' width="250px"class="mascota" id="mascota" alt="imagen">
        </div>
        <div id="container-status">
            <h1>estado</h1>
            hambre    <progress id="hambre" class="progreso" max="100" value="100"></progress><br>
            suciedad  <progress id="suciedad" class="progreso" max="100" value="100"></progress><br>
            sueño     <progress id="suenho" class="progreso" max="100" value="100"></progress><br>
            diversión <progress id="diversion" class="progreso" max="100" value="100"></progress><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="botones">
        
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-comer" >comer</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-duchar" >duchar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-dormir" >dormir</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-jugar" >jugar</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
window.onload = function(){
    var btn_duchar = document.getElementById("btn-duchar");
    btn_duchar.addEventListener("click",duchar);

    ejecutar_imagenes_con_condiciones();

}

var hambre = document.getElementById("hambre");
var suciedad = document.getElementById("suciedad");
var suenho = document.getElementById("suenho");
var diversion = document.getElementById("diversion");

mover_barra_suciedad(suciedad.getAttribute("value"));

//mover barra - cambiar valores al atributo
function mover_barra_suciedad(i){
    console.log(i);
    var btn_duchar = document.getElementById("btn-duchar");
    let hiloSuciedad=setInterval(function (){
            i=i-2;
            suciedad.setAttribute("value", i);
            //console.log(i);
        if(i<=0 ){
            clearInterval(hiloSuciedad);
        }
        
    },1000);
    if(duchar){
        console.log("entra");
        return;
    }
function duchar(){
console.log(suciedad.getAttribute("value"));

suciedad.setAttribute("value", 100);
mover_barra_suciedad();
console.log("aqui abajo ostia");
console.log(suciedad.getAttribute("value"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi de este modo me funciona (las explicaciones en el propio código):

```js
// asignamos a un objeto el botón
var btn_duchar = document.getElementById("btn-duchar");
// lo ponemos a la escucha del evento click para lanzar la función ducha
btn_duchar.addEventListener("click", duchar);
// asignamos a un objeto la barra de progreso con id suciedad
var suciedad = document.getElementById("suciedad");
// hacemos la variable que usaremos para setInterval disponible globalmente
var hiloSuciedad = null
// iniciamos la suciedad
mover_barra_suciedad(suciedad.getAttribute("value"));

function mover_barra_suciedad(i) {
  hiloSuciedad = setInterval(function() {
    suciedad.setAttribute("value", i);
    i = i - 2;
  }, 1000);
}

function duchar() {
  // paramos el setInterval
  clearInterval(hiloSuciedad);
  // reseteamos la variable
  hiloSuciedad = null;
  // rearrancamos la suciedad
  mover_barra_suciedad("100");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="tamagochi2.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tamagochi.css" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="container-img">
        <img src='./img/gato.png' width="250px" class="mascota" id="mascota" alt="imagen">
      </div>
      <div id="container-status">
        <h1>estado</h1>
        hambre <progress id="hambre" class="progreso" max="100" value="100"></progress><br>
        suciedad <progress id="suciedad" class="progreso" max="100" value="100"></progress><br>
        sueño <progress id="suenho" class="progreso" max="100" value="100"></progress><br>
        diversión <progress id="diversion" class="progreso" max="100" value="100"></progress><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="botones">

      <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-comer">comer</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-duchar">duchar</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-dormir">dormir</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-jugar">jugar</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

aquí dejo mi aportación de como yo lo haría.

Lo que he echo es crear una clase para no tener que escribir más código de la cuenta, y sea más fácil de gestionar.

Aquí abajo te dejo el código, si tienes alguna duda no dudes en comentármelo.

```js
class Progress{
        constructor(element, button, valueToIncreasePerSecond = 1, valueToDecreasePerSecond = 3, value = 100, intervalTime = 1000){
            this.element = element;
            this.button = button;
            this.valueToIncreasePerSecond = valueToIncreasePerSecond;
            this.valueToDecreasePerSecond = valueToDecreasePerSecond;
            this.value = value;
            this.intervalTime = intervalTime;
            this.originalValue = value;

            button.addEventListener("click", this.Action.bind(this), false);
        }

        Action(){
            if(this.value <= 0) return;
            if((this.value + this.valueToIncreasePerSecond) >= 100) this.value = 100;
            else this.value += this.valueToIncreasePerSecond;
            this.UpdateProgress();
            }

        StartInterval(){
            this.loop = setInterval(() => {
                this.value -= this.valueToDecreasePerSecond;
                this.UpdateProgress();
            if(this.value <= 0){
                clearInterval(this.loop);
            }
            },this.intervalTime);
        }

        Restart(){
            this.value = this.originalValue
            clearInterval(this.loop)
            this.StartInterval();
            this.UpdateProgress();

        }

        UpdateProgress(){
            this.element.setAttribute("value", this.value);
        }
    }



    const suciedad = new Progress(document.querySelector("#suciedad"), document.querySelector("#btn-duchar"), 4, 15, 100, 2500);
    suciedad.StartInterval();

    const comer = new Progress(document.querySelector("#hambre"), document.querySelector("#btn-comer"), 7, 10, 100, 1500);
    comer.StartInterval();

    const dormir = new Progress(document.querySelector("#suenho"), document.querySelector("#btn-dormir"), 1, 20, 100, 5500);
    dormir.StartInterval();
    
    const jugar = new Progress(document.querySelector("#diversion"), document.querySelector("#btn-jugar"), 50, 20, 100, 500);
    jugar.StartInterval();

    const progress = [suciedad, comer, dormir,jugar];

    function RestartAll(){
        progress.forEach(n => n.Restart())
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="container-img">
            <img src='./img/gato.png' width="250px"class="mascota" id="mascota" alt="imagen">
        </div>
        <button onclick="RestartAll()">Restart</button>
        <div id="container-status">
            <h1>estado</h1>
            hambre    <progress id="hambre" class="progreso" max="100" value="100"></progress><br>
            suciedad  <progress id="suciedad" class="progreso" max="100" value="100"></progress><br>
            sueño     <progress id="suenho" class="progreso" max="100" value="100"></progress><br>
            diversión <progress id="diversion" class="progreso" max="100" value="100"></progress><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="botones">
        
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-comer" >comer</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-duchar" >duchar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-dormir" >dormir</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-jugar" >jugar</button>
    </div>
</body>
```